# Can't catch events using SetWinEventHook. Will get event after using accevent32.exe

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, events

Does anyone get the following problem?
I write a dll to load into another process to get EVENT_OBJECT_VALUECHANGE event for a window in that process. The code looks like as below.

```
void CALLBACK WinEventProc(
            HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook,
            DWORD event,
            HWND hwnd,
            LONG idObject,
            LONG idChild,
            DWORD dwEventThread,
            DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    if(event == EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE && hwnd)
    {
      .....
    }
}

SetWinEventHook(1u, 0x7FFFFFFFu,  
            ModuleFromAddress(PIURouter),
            WinEventProc,
            dwProcess,  //the window in that process
            dwThread, //the window in that thread
            WINEVENT_INCONTEXT|WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);
```

I am sure that the DLL is loaded into that process and WinEventProc is called, just can not catch the event I want. I'm sure that event is happened in every half second.

But right after I use accevent32.exe and include the events only for that window. I can see the EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE. Close accevent32.exe and run my app again. Now  EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE is caught by WinEventProc.

I decompile the event32.dll from accevent32.exe. Don't see any special functions called. Also the windows properties, styles and procedure are not changed after running accevent32.exe.

Any advice?

Comment: Using WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS when you inject a DLL is ... odd.  Do note that SetWinEventHook() doesn't require DLL injection.  Event.dll does use a special function, ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx().

Comment: Using WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS to make sure event hook doesn't work for the process which installs the hook, usually it is my app. DLL injection is my purpose to run my code into the target application.

Comment: I searched the function ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx which seems control the windows messages instead of events. However I will give it a try.

Comment: Well, that's the odd part.  "Own process" is now the process in which you injected the DLL.  It is *not* the process you used to start the injection.

Comment: From msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, I think WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS is the same as WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD which prevents this instance of the hook from receiving the events that are generated by the thread that is registering this hook. It seems the example in that page also prove it.